# Core Data KVC example

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

Sorry to impose, but I would really appreciate it if someone would take a look at this and show me how to get this done:

Core Data works as expected with data associations between the Source list entry(s) and the upper right textField.

So does textField2 (lower right) *if you manually type in a string*.

I want to append a string in the lower textField, in this case a generic "Hello!" (implemented in the setText method) and have it also maintain it's association with the source list entry.

To summarize: textField2 - manually type in a string, it works as expected. Append the coded string, and it does not maintain it's association with the source list entry.

Here's the [sample project](https://s3.amazonaws.com/code-examples/kvc.zip).

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please post all relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I updated `setText:` method in `MyDocument` class:

```
-(IBAction)setText:(id)sender
{       
    NSString *newValue = [[output stringValue] stringByAppendingString:@"Hello!"];
    [[setText selection] setValue:newValue forKey:@"textField2"];
}
```

I think your assumptions on value setting direction was wrong. Object does not take a value from the text field. It's the text field that takes value from the object. Hence I create `newValue` by taking current value of `output` text field and appending something to it. Then I take `[setText selection]` object (the one currently selected) and set it's `textField2` property to new value. This `setValue:forKey` method automatically updates the `output` test field with new value of `textField2` property.